# install maven 3.6.0 on Mac

Tags: macos, maven

I am trying to install a specific version of man.brew install maven@3.6.0 is not working due to lack of 3.6 version (there is 3.5, 3.2, 3.3). installation with this guide https://maven.apache.org/install.html also not.
zsh: man not found
Any ideas?

Comment: Install most recent version...simply download it from maven.apache.org ....

Comment: I  need version 3.6.0

Comment: Why? Use the most recent ones... furthermore you can download an old version (but only 3.6.3) https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/ to get the 3.6.0 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.0/

Comment: In the requirements it is specified to use 3.6.0, I actually dont know exactly why. Yeah I found the file to download but cannot install it

Comment: If the requirement says 3.6.0, just use 3.8.x. You will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Maven Version Manager](https://mvnvm.org/) to manage multiple versions of maven. You can have a folder-specific maven version.

**Steps**

1. If you already installed the maven brew formula uninstall it `brew remove --force maven`
2. Install `mvnvm`. `brew install mvnvm`
3. To set the global maven version add an environment variable named `DEFAULT_MVN_VERSION` with the maven version you want as default as the value.
4. To set a Maven version for a specific folder create a file named `mvnvm.properties` in that folder and have the following content.

   ```
   mvn_version=<maven version for the folder>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Never heard about Maven Version Manager before. This makes it a breeze to use different versions of maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 3.6.3 binaries from here

https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/

Just saw and struggled for a bit before getting to the `wget` command

Comment: Please avoid using vulgar language such as "bro".